# Display unix time in specific timezone in AM/PM format in Python

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, pytz

I have a large spreadsheet of unix times and corresponding timezones. Row 1 column 1 may be `1538082000` and column 2 would be `America/New_York`, row 2 may be `1538083000` and `America/Los_Angeles`. In each case I need them in the format of the time it'd be for someone inside of that timezone.

For example, in my EDT example (row 1) I'd want `Sept 27, 2018 5:00:00PM EDT` and for row 2 I'd want `Sept 27, 2018 2:16:40PM PDT`.

I run into this every so often when trying to scrape data and display it in a more friendly format for 3rd parties and I've never been able to find an especially good way of doing this.

Comment: Have you tried to look into some existing libraries for it? There are quite a few popular ones that can solve this easily, such as https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and https://pendulum.eustace.io/

Comment: I have not! Will look into them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io):

```
>>> import arrow
>>> utc =  arrow.Arrow.fromtimestamp(1538082000)
>>> conv = utc.to('America/New_York')
>>> conv.format("MMM D, YYYY h:mm:ssA ") + conv.tzname()
```

Results in: `Sep 27, 2018 5:00:00PM EDT`

For your second example:

```
>>> from dateutil import tz
>>> t = arrow.Arrow.fromtimestamp(1538083000, tzinfo=tz.gettz("America/Los_Angeles"))
>>> t.format("MMM D, YYYY h:mm:ssA ") + t.tzname()
```

Results in `Sep 27, 2018 2:16:40PM PDT`.

You can either use the first form using `to` or you can pass `tzinfo` to `fromtimestamp` like in the second example. Personally, I think that the first form looks cleaner.

Comment: Perfect! The arrow library seems so much more sane than python's built-in functionality. Adding it to my box of libraries to always have on hand!

Answer (score 1):

A solution without using Arrow.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

def convert_time(timestamp, tz):
    tzinfo = timezone(tz)
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    fmt = "%b %d, %Y %-I:%M:%S%p "
    return dt.astimezone(tzinfo).strftime(fmt) + tzinfo.tzname(dt)

>>> ts = "1538082000"
>>> tz = "America/New_York"
>>> convert_time(int(ts), tz)
>>> Sep 27, 2018 5:00:00PM EDT

>>> ts2 = "1538083000"
>>> tz2 = "America/Los_Angeles"
>>> convert_time(int(ts2), tz2)
>>> Sep 27, 2018 2:16:40PM PDT
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime.strftime()`

import datetime

```
t = 1538082000

dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)

formatted = dt.strftime("%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")

formatted
>>> Sep 28, 2018 07:00:00
```

According to the docs, time.time() produces a timestamp from 1/1/1970 UTC. So you can then use that information to add/subtract hours based on timezone.

E.g. Melbourne/Sydney (UTC+10:00)

```
t = 1538082000

dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)

tz_dt = dt + datetime.timedelta(hours=10)

tz_dt.strftime("%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")

tz_dt
>>> 2018-09-28 17:00:00
```

[Here](http://strftime.org/) are the docs for strftime, which will help format your answer.

Comment: I actually need it in a specific timezone. I'm specifically interested in finding the local time in a specific timezone that is not necessarily my local time. Significantly clarified my question!

Comment: How would I go about getting the integer number of hours offset for each timezone to insert into the timedelta and know if it's + or - hours off UTC? And `fromtimestamp()` returns the local time on my machine, so in my case (on a laptop in CDT) your example returns `Sep 28, 2018 02:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Using `%I` will format Hour into `12-hour time`, and `%p` will return `AM/PM`.
Using `pytz` can also work:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz


def convert_time(timestamp, tz):
    eastern = pytz.timezone('UTC')
    tzinfo = pytz.timezone(tz)
    loc_dt = eastern.localize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp))
    fmt = "%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S%p %Z"
    return loc_dt.astimezone(tzinfo).strftime(fmt)


ts = "1538082000"
tz = "America/New_York"
print(convert_time(int(ts), tz))

>> Sep 28, 2018 05:00:00PM EDT

ts = "1538083000"
tz = "America/Los_Angeles"
print(convert_time(int(ts), tz))

>> Sep 28, 2018 02:16:40PM PDT
```

Comment: Hey, I clarified my question to be a bit more clear about what I'm looking for. I'm specifically interested in finding the local time in a specific timezone that is not necessarily my local time.

Comment: @NickCatal I update my answer, using pytz can also work and maybe more easy to you